# No AuthenticationProvider found for UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-3

my web.xml config is

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

here is my security config

```
    <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/*.ico"  filters="none" />


</http>

 <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="net.spring3.provider.MyAuthProvider"  />

    <authentication-manager>

        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" /> 

    </authentication-manager>
```

Here is my customAuthProvider class

```
public class MyAuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider  {


    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


     @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        private static Map<String, String> SIMPLE_USERS = new HashMap<String, String>(2) {{
            put("joe", "joe");
            put("bob", "bob");
        }};

        @SuppressWarnings("serial" )
        private static List<GrantedAuthority> AUTHORITIES = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(1) {{
            add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));
        }};

        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException
        {
            // All your user authentication needs
            System.out.println("==Authenticate Me==");
            if (SIMPLE_USERS.containsKey(auth.getPrincipal()) 
                && SIMPLE_USERS.get(auth.getPrincipal()).equals(auth.getCredentials()))
            {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.getName(), auth.getCredentials(), AUTHORITIES);
            }
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Username/Password does not match for " + auth.getPrincipal());
        }




}
```

The page shows the login form and when I enter bob and bob as login , it throws up the following error.

```
Your login attempt was not successful, try again.

Reason: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
```

I checked the logs at debug level ALL and here is what I get.

```
FINE: Request is to process authentication
Nov 17, 2011 5:37:36 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext publishEvent
FINEST: Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationFailureProviderNotFoundEvent[source=org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@ffff8dfd: Principal: sd; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffe3f86: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: x4lg4vtktpw9; Not granted any authorities]
Nov 17, 2011 5:37:36 AM org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter unsuccessfulAuthentication
FINE: Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
```

Any help on this..what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Just after posting this.I read from spring doc that the method should return true to indicate that the provider supports authentication. And I was returning false !!! , I just changed it to true and my first spring security app login is working successfully !! Hope this information will be useful for anyone who was stuck just like me.

@Override
    public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return  true;
    }

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As you already wrote in your comment the problem is that you always return `false` in the `supports()` method of your autentication provider. But instead of always returning `true` you should check the `authentication` you get like this:

```
public class MyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider, Serializable {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
        return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: In my integration test I am getting this error message. But my `supports() `method returns `true`.(It does - I printed). What else can cause this error?

Comment: I had this error when I accidentally had two `UserDetailsService` beans configured.

Comment: @MatthewWise Your comment saved my day!!!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. In my case the solution was to set `AbstractAuthenticationToken.setAuthenticated()` to `true` after the authentication passed.

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**")).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"));
        return http.build();
    }
```

I got the same exception. In my case i got a request with an Authorization Header of type Basic, which i didn't needed to process. So i just deleted this line:

> .httpBasic(withDefaults())